# Running a .cmd file from Ant

Tags: ant

Is it possible to run a command (.cmd file) from Ant? Would I need to write Java code for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<exec executable="cmd" os="Windows XP">
  <arg value="/C"/>
  <arg value="command to run"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: If I need to run a cmd/bat file to prepare the environment before I run an .exe in an upcoming Ant task, how does that work? I used this method and it appears to execute my cmd file, but then the following .exe is not aware of this and complains that the env hasn't been prepared.

Comment: I tried with `<arg value="cls">` and, while there are no errors, and it logs the fact that it is executing something, it doesn't clear the command window. Why is this? Also tried writing cls to a .bat and .cmd file and executing that. 
Is it possible to clear the windows command window from ant through some other means?

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by using the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task.  From the ant exec documentation:

> Note that .bat files cannot in general by executed directly. One normally needs to execute the command shell executable cmd  using the /c switch.

So you would need to do something like:

```
<exec executable="cmd">
  <arg value="/c"/>
  <arg value="batchfile.cmd"/>
</exec>
```

Note that by doing this you have created a dependency of running your ant script in windows.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to eradicus answer, you can also execute .bat, .cmd, ... from any directory with argument on your Window machine by

```
<target name="test">        
    <exec executable="cmd" dir="C:/Users/mydir/">
        <arg value="/C" />
        <arg value="myjob.bat arg1 arg2" />                         
    </exec>     
</target>
```