# call shell script from ant

Tags: shell, ant, cygwin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running a .cmd file from ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713350/running-a-cmd-file-from-ant)

Is it possible to call a shell script from ant script on a windows machine by installing cygwin on it?
I have 2 shell scripts that need to be called from an ant script. The ant script is used to build the code from a windows machine. The first shell script needs to be called in between the ant execution after which some other processing would be done using ant and after this the second ant script needs to be called. Can you please let me know the ant command to do the same.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927975/is-there-a-way-to-have-ant-create-a-shell-or-batch-runtime-script

Comment: consider using a continous integration tool like jenkins : http://jenkins-ci.org/